# Are these preloaded images being used correctly?

Tags: jquery, image, preload

This is quite specific, so I couldn't just find an answer on the internet!

I have some code that is loading in some images that I want to be displayed on hover. Everything works fine but sometimes there is a delay when clicking a checkbox in divs where the hover function is being used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$icons = [];

$('#boat_icon').hide();

jQuery('.boat_row').each(function(e){
            $icons.push('url("' + $(this).attr("id") + '")');
            });

jQuery($icons).each(function(e){

jQuery('#boat_icon').css('background-image', this);

console.log(this + "loaded!");

});

$('#boat_icon').show();
});

 jQuery('.boat_row').hover(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $(this).css('background-color', 'D8EAFF')

     var iconpath = $(this).attr("id");
     $('#boat_icon').css('background-image', 'url("'+iconpath+'")');
     },

     function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', '')
 });
```

The iconpath is a string in the database, so I was wondering... is this the correct way to use preloaded images? Because the images are loaded on ready, are they then being used from the cache or are they being loaded again every time on hover because im not displaying a stored image object?

Comment: In the end it's depending on the browser where  images are loaded from. You may try to improve the appereance by using CSS-sprites and configuring File-ETags

Comment: consider using image sprites and then just changing he background position with CSS, no js needed

Comment: Dr.Molle, Moin Zaman, Ive seen the use of CSS sprites using background positioning but had never used them before. Was in a bit of a rush to release this application so didnt have time to learn this time around, but thanks for the input. I had a look into them :) Very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this preloading:

```
if (document.images)
{
  pic1= new Image(100,25); 
  pic1.src="http://someplace.com/image1.gif"; 
}
```

`if (document.images)` is used to verify doesn't browser support preloading for images

Comment: This is what I had seen around, but unfortunately didnt seem ideal to use for this application. Thanks for the input!